# How to modify css to "box-shadow" to portrait or landscape image dynamically

Tags: php, css

I am looking to have the below code to dynamically change the box-shadow to match the image orientation. . . either landscape or portrait.  Here is a link to an example:  http://gbamedical.com/test3.php  It currently looks funny when a portrait image is left orientated with landscape box.  Also looking to have thumbnails the same height which would require portrait thumbnails to be narrower.

The CSS:

```
style>* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}


.slider {
width: 640px;
position: relative;
padding-top: 480px;
margin: 20px auto;
box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.slider > img {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
transition: all 0.5s;
}

.slider input {
display: none;
}

.slider label {
width: 60px;
margin: 20px 2px;
float: left;
border: 2px solid #999;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all 0.5s;
opacity: 0.6;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider label img {
width: 100%;
display: block;
}

.slider input:checked + label {
border-color: #666;
opacity: 1;
}

.slider input ~ img {
opacity: 0;
transform: scale(1.1);
}

.slider input:checked + label + img {
opacity: 1;
transform: scale(1);
}
</style>
```

The PHP code:

```
<div class="slider">
<?php
$array = glob('ebayimg/8851gba050516/size_2/*');
$i = 1;
foreach($array as $image) {
?>
<input type="radio" name="slide" id="image<?php echo $i ?>" <?php if($i == 1){      ?> checked <?php } ?>/>
<label for="image<?php echo $i ?>">
    <img src="http://www.gbamedical.com/<?php echo $image ?>"/>
</label>
<img src="http://www.gbamedical.com/<?php echo $image ?>" height="480"/>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to use javascript to change it on the fly by getting the width of the image and changing the `.slider` width accordingly:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("label").on('click',function() {
        var preview =   $(this).next();
        var getW    =   preview.width();
        $(".slider").css({"width":getW*.91});
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is a [jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yznecj3d/)

---

**EDIT**

Try this set of styles:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.slider {
  max-width: 640px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 480px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider > img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.slider input {
  display: none;
}

.slider label {
  height: 60px;
  margin: 20px 2px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0.6;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider label img {
  max-height: 60px;
  display: block;
}

.slider input:checked + label {
  border-color: #666;
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider input ~ img {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.slider input:checked + label + img {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

[Here is a jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qzp0rnoL/1/) with the css above.

Comment: This look is exactly what I am looking for BUT unfortunately my use is on eBay and they are shutting down all listings that use 'active content' so I was hoping for a way without javascript.  I have been using an elegant image gallery that uses javascript  for years but I have less than a month to switch over.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that is a problem then. I am not sure how you could do that with CSS explicitly! Let me see if I can fiddle a bit more with just css...but it's not my strong suit...

Comment: I REALLY appreciate your effort / help!  Thank you!

Comment: Definitely looks MUCH better. ..  if it could be centered it would be perfect.  Also, I'd like to try and get the thumbnails all a uniform height (the 'portrait' images would obviously be narrower).    THANKS for your help!

Comment: Check now, the thumbnails are uniform, but you will need to probably add some other html to get the main image to center. What throws that off is the `position: absolute;` and `left: 0;` in the `.slider > img` class.

Comment: This is great!  Thank you so much!  I am new to stackoverflow. . ..   What did I do wrong to receive a -2 feedback / vote on my original post?

Comment: It's hard to say, the one close vote was because it was unclear to someone, but sometimes people don't feel like the OP (you in this case) did enough work to solve the issue. Could be just about anything really. If no one leaves a comment explaining their downvote it's sometimes hard to tell. I've seen some horrible questions (in my opinion) get upvote or not have any votes to close it, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thank you!  You have been a huge help!